# How do I scale and rotate bones without stretching the mesh?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

Ok, in short I have scaled the bones of a mesh to make a character look like a "dwarf" or "chibi" version of itself. However this seems to have applied as a pose and not a change to the armature. If I delete the pose, the mesh returns to its original state (as if I'd done nothing).

The problem is that I did this scaling with the character in T-Pose and trying to actually pose the character now causes parts to stretch and warp like they're Mr. Fantastic.

For example, if I rotate the shin bone to bend the knee, the shin and foot now elongate weirdly and out of proportion. How can I prevent this from happening?

My goal is to have the character remain posable in their new "dwarf" form as if that were the new normal. I'm not terribly well-versed in Blender for this sort of thing, so I may need a "for dummies" explanation.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try to duplicate the Armature modifier, and apply the copy, it should apply the new limb proportions

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words, please ... you lost me.

Comment: I recommend you apply the armature modifier on the mesh, then go into pose mode on the armature, select all, and “apply as rest pose.“ Then, relink the mesh to the armature with a new armature modifier.